# Password toggle icon inside bootstrap field

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I have a react-bootstrap field which is used to enter a password. I'm in need of adding a password show button inside the field. Something like this

[image]

I have already changed the default correct icon with my icon as follows.

```
 .form-control.is-valid,
 .was-validated .form-control:valid {
  background-image: url("../../assets/icons/Tick.png") !important;
  background-size: 24px 24px !important;
}
```

How can i add the password toggle icon which should be clickable as well.

My password field (react-bootstrap)

```
<Form.Group controlId="formPassword" style={{ marginBottom: '32px' }}>
       <Form.Label className="label_type2">My password will be</Form.Label>
       <Form.Control type="password" className="input_text" id="pass_icon" placeholder="" required />
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: Are you able to supply your HTML so we can have a full working example to go off?

Comment: hello can you please provide the code in codesandbox or copepen

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you. Show Password- button reveals the password in input field.

```
const[revealed, setRevealed]= useState(false);

    const handleReveal=()=>{
        setRevealed(true)
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <input type={(revealed) ? "text" : "password"} />
        <button onClick={handleReveal}>Show Password</button>
    </div>
```